# cross-domain iframe realtime url detect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want create a web page like www.domain.com/iframe that load a cross-domain website on it like yahoo.com.
visitor want browse on iframe page (yahoo.com) and my main page must always detect iframe url.

Because ross-domain iframe policy its not access it via

```
document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.location.href;
```

I do some googling on it, ways like [jquery PostMessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) , [porxy ifrmae](http://www.tomslabs.com/index.php/2012/06/iframes-and-javascript-cross-domain-security/) .... but It not work for me. my iframe is not on my access to add java functions.

I dont have coercion to use iframe, I want a technique to show an other link on my page and know position of that other view on my page to do some things...

please help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can do it

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
Links: <br />
<a title="http://validator.w3.org/">w3c.com</a><br />
<a title="http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Accueil_principal">wiki in french</a><br />

<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://www.google.fr" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("a").click(function () {
     var $urls = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#myiframe").attr("src", $urls);
     return false;
  });
});
 </script>
```

.attr() will change the src="" of your iframe. Now you can just interact the attr with an event like on click or whatever you want.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply.maybe I explain bad.
please see my real page : http://bit.ly/1448O9S
In top of page url pf iframe showed. I want whene user click on a link in iframe,in top page url changed.and flow it.
thanks

Comment: i showed you how the script may be... Don't you know about jquery? if note check [link]http://jquery.com/

I will edit my post and show you a complete code. Please check again very soon

Comment: I am very thankful for your replies. I know jquery normal for use.Your code is : change Iframe src via main page via click event,... But I need inverse of that.
here is a question like my need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766281/getting-iframe-current-src-url-in-cross-domain

I want reat an Iframe with a start link like yahoo.com. your click on Iframe links like yahoo images,.... inside iframe not on my main page, so I need trakc user iframe url, .

Comment: For some obvious security reason, it is impossible to interact from an iframe to the parent page